# Ember js - Cannot generate URL with dynamic segments using urlFor method

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am able to generate a URL using `urlFor()` when I’m in the route `/1/1/orders`. but I’m unable to generate a URL in the application route.

So this code is not working:

```
var routeName = "scope.purchase.invoice";
var dynamicSegments = { scopeId: 1, scopeData: 2, invoiceId: 3, pageSize: 20, pageIndex: 1 };
var url = this.router.urlFor(routeName, 1, 2, 3, 10, 1);
console.log("inside generated url", url);
```

For this `router.js`:

```
this.route("scope", { path: '/:scopeId/:scopeData' }, function(){
  this.route("purchase", function(){
    this.route("invoice", { path: '/:invoiceId/:pageIndex/:pageSize' });
  })
});
```

here is the reference [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a50d50c188d78ba97221d2dc0996f9dd?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that [`urlFor()` takes the *models* / *dynamic segments* as individual, ordered params, not a object with keys and values.](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.16/classes/RouterService/methods/urlFor?anchor=urlFor).

So do this:

```
const url = this.router.urlFor(routeName, dynamicSegments.scopeId, dynamicSegments.scropeData, dynamicSegments.invoiceId, dynamicSegments.pageSize, dynamicSegments.pageIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks for your info,

Much appreciated, if you could explain this scenario, I can able to make URL with a single object if I was in the route “/1/1/orders”.

Comment: what do you mean? If you want to discuss this maybe consider to join the ember community Discord channel (see [here](https://emberjs.com/community))